# mysql - how is it possible to have a foreign key on columns with different definitions

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a really strange issue (well... not an issue because it doesn't really generate any problems... yet). On one of my databases I have a foreign key linking 2 columns with different definitions (INT(10) UNSIGNED and INT(11) UNSIGNED). This may suggest that they are the same? Or is some sort of strange bug?

Here you can see the create tables (directly from cli, no clients used to be sure is not a client bug):

```
Database changed

mysql> show create table faq;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| faq   | CREATE TABLE `faq` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url_string` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `section_id` (`section_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=89 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table faq_questions_tags;
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table              | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| faq_questions_tags | CREATE TABLE `faq_questions_tags` (
  `id_faq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_faq`,`id_tag`),
  KEY `faq_tags_tags_id_fk` (`id_tag`),
  CONSTRAINT `faq_tags_faq_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_faq`) REFERENCES `faq` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `faq_tags_tags_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tag`) REFERENCES `faq_tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see faq_questions_tags.id_faq references faq.id, no errors/warnings are reported even thought they have different definitions. How is that possible? The theory states it shouldn't be.

Comment: This appears to be a laxity permitted by MySQL, but to be certain, the SQL standard would either require or strongly suggest that the types of the foreign and primary key do in fact match exactly.  And on other databases, your code wouldn't work.

Comment: According to the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html), `INTEGER[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]` is a synonym for INT for any permissible M, so the two apparently different types are in effect the same identical type.